# When is SOME optional?

Tags: grammar

I am stuck in a debate with an American over the use of the word SOME in "I want to change some money." In the UK, we would use the word 'some'. I'm told it's often omitted in the States. I'm fine with that - except now she dismisses  the use of 'some' as vernacular. What do you think?

Comment: "I want to change money" sounds weird to me as someone who grew up in the Northeast, but as is often the case, when it comes down to subtle differences like this, there may be variation on a sub-national level.

Comment: Look up 'vernacular'. What do _you_ think? (The primary adjectival sense given by AHDEL can hardly be said to warrant the use of 'dismisses'.) By the same token, the omission of 'some' is equally vernacular.

Comment: *Some* means part of a number, but not necessarily all of it. Therefore, if you are exchanging some of your money, you would say, "I want to change some money." I am an American, and it sounds like your American friend is not too handy with the English language. I would ignore her argument.

Comment: *I went to the shop today and bought some bananas, some pears, some milk, some yoghurt, some minced beef and a newspaper. Whilst I was there I didn't need to get any money from the cash machine as I already had some.* I could have said *I went to the shop today and bought bananas,pears, milk, yoghurt, minced beef, and a newspaper. Whilst I was there I didn't need money from the cash machine as I already had **some***.  Either of these are acceptable to any reasonable person and I don't see the point of getting in a stew over which is better.

Comment: @WS2 said what I would have said. Those who think *change money* is bizarre: do you ever say *make money*, or do you always say *make some money* and (won't) *make any money*?

Comment: This seems like a case of the locality illusion in operation.

Comment: The American you spoke to definitely wasn't me, because I would have said "I want to change some money," just as you did.

Answer (score -1):

If you say "I want to change money", somebody might think that you want to do it as your job.
"I want to change some money" is definitely better, if you mean here and now.